# Store methods in separate file. Android

Tags: android

I have small andoid app, which asks the user some questions. The questions are set up in this format:

```
private void generalKnowledgeQuestions(){
    questions = new ArrayList<>();
    //the first option is the button on the left. if the boolean set to false then the second option is correct
    questions.add(new QuestionObject("Where was the picture taken?", true, R.drawable.cuba, "cuba", "singapore", "the picture has cars in it!"));
    questions.add(new QuestionObject("This city is in which country?", false, R.drawable.barcelona, "Hungary", "Spain", "The beaches of barcelona"));}
```

And many more of these...

I was wondering if I could put this method in a separate file, for updating the questions more easily, and not having to come inside the activity file where accidents can happen?
thanks

Comment: you can use a text file and then use that text file

Comment: yes, I was thinking something like that, only thing, I don't know how :D

Comment: you can create an XML file and save all your data there, or any json file. there are many ways to do it.

Comment: make a text file (in html format ) and put into assets folder and use the stringbuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a QuestionUtils class which contains this method in a static context. Like this:

```
public abstract class QuestionUtils {

public static ArrayList<Question> generalKnowledgeQuestions(){
       ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
       //the first option is the button on the left. if the boolean set to false then the second option is correct
       questions.add(new QuestionObject("Where was the picture taken?", true, R.drawable.cuba, "cuba", "singapore", "the picture has cars in it!"));
       questions.add(new QuestionObject("This city is in which country?", false, R.drawable.barcelona, "Hungary", "Spain", "The beaches of barcelona"));

       return questions;
   }
}
```

I would recommend keeping your question `String` data inside an xml file.

As requested to reference this method from another class you would simply have to call `QuestionUtils.generalKnowledgeQuestions();` The method would return an `Array` of your questions to you, I don't know what you have called your question `Object` so change `Question` to whatever you are using.

Comment: thanks. I appreciate the time you have taken to answer, I however can't use it, because I get some errors, and I don't know how to solve them, and also, don't know the next steps, how to use this class in my existing class...

Comment: also xml file is a good idea, but again, don't know how. I'll keep googling though. :D

Comment: if it helps, here is the full project: https://github.com/City-of-Bath-College/android-assignment-soosgyul

Comment: Thanks! :D you helped a lot! :D